# how to set java my links

Tags: javascript, jquery

my site download box

```
<div class="linkdl">
<?php 

$dl_320 =get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dl320', true);

?>
<?php if(!empty($dl_320)) { echo '<a href="'.$dl_320.'">Download MP3 </a>'; } ?>

 </div>
```

Now How I set  The Code

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="enter"/>

<script>

    function myFunction(){
        alert("You button was pressed");
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know from your question that you are trying like :

```
<?
php if(!empty($dl_320)) { 
echo "<a href='".$dl_320."' onclick='return myFunction();'>Download MP3 </a>"; 
} ?>
<script>
function myFunction(){ 
alert("You button was pressed"); 
};
</script>
```

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 site   wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=single.php

Comment: that is your code i added onclick='return myFunction();' with that.please handle quotes properly like the answer

Comment: after adding  
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: if you remove ?

Comment: working well for me..should be some other error in your code

Comment: hi plz chek stackoverflow.com/questions/44347467/change-popup-model-code-in-every-page-of-a-site

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your function to an event.

For instance:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){ alert("You button was pressed"); };

    jQuery('a').click(myFunction);
</scrip>
```